# A tight upper bound for Gaussian integral.

Tags: integration, inequality, normal-distribution

Consider two positive real number $\mu$ and $\sigma$. Let $m = 1, 2, \ldots$ be the natural number, I want to find a tight upper bound for the following part Gaussian integral:
$$\int_0^{\infty} \exp \left[ - \frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2} \right] x^m \, \mathrm{d} x.$$
A naive way for $m$ is even, we can use
$$
    \begin{aligned}
        \int_0^{\infty} \exp \left[ - \frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2} \right] x^m \, \mathrm{d} x & \leq \int_{-{\infty}}^{\infty} \exp \left[ - \frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2} \right] x^m \, \mathrm{d} x \\
        & = \sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2} \int_{-{\infty}}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}}\exp \left[ - \frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2} \right] x^m \, \mathrm{d} x \\
        & = \sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}\mathrm{E} \left[ \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2) \right]^m \\
        & = \sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2} \sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{m}{2}\right\rfloor}\left(\begin{array}{c}m \\ 2 j\end{array}\right) \frac{\mu^{m-2 j} \sigma^{2 j}(2 j) !}{j ! 2^j}.
    \end{aligned}
$$
However, this method will lose a lot of information containing in the integral interval $(0, \infty)$. Besides, we cannot apply this method when $m$ is odd. I wounder whether there exists an improved approach to deal with this integral? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the very first inequality is false if $m$ is odd.

Comment: @SmallDeviation Thanks. Revised!

Comment: I think I can derive an asymptotic formula. Are you familiar with Laplace’s method?

Comment: @bob Yes! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $$I_m=\int_0^{\infty} \exp \left[ - \frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2} \right] x^m \, dx$$
$$\frac{I_m}{2^{\frac{m-1}{2}} \sigma ^m }=\sqrt{2} \mu  \Gamma \left(\frac{m+2}{2}\right) \,
   _1F_1\left(\frac{1-m}{2};\frac{3}{2};-\frac{\mu ^2}{2 \sigma
   ^2}\right)+$$ $$\sigma  \Gamma \left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right) \,
   _1F_1\left(-\frac{m}{2};\frac{1}{2};-\frac{\mu ^2}{2 \sigma
   ^2}\right)$$ where appears Kummer confluent hypergeometric function.

Let $\mu=\sqrt{2} \sigma  t$

$$\frac{I_m}{2^{\frac{m-1}{2}} \sigma ^{m+1} }=2 \,t\, \Gamma \left(\frac{m}{2}+1\right) \,
   _1F_1\left(\frac{1-m}{2};\frac{3}{2};-t^2\right)+$$ $$\Gamma \left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right) \,
   _1F_1\left(-\frac{m}{2};\frac{1}{2};-t^2\right)$$

*Not proved*, it seems that the second term is slightly larger than the first term.

$$\frac{I_m}{2^{\frac{m-1}{2}} \sigma ^{m+1} }< 2\,\Gamma \left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right) \,
   _1F_1\left(-\frac{m}{2};\frac{1}{2};-t^2\right)$$

For example, using $\mu=3$, $\sigma=1$ and $m=5$, the exact value is $1398.699006$ while the bound is $1398.699435$.

*At this point, I am stuck.*

Comment: Thanks! The next step may be to find a rigorous proof for the second term slightly larger than the first term and a nice upper bound for $_1 F_1$

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, there's a readily available [formula](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11123-013-0381-8#Sec3) for the moments of the truncated normal distribution, so any 'tight' bound will only be a corruption of the exact formula. For reference, let $J_m(\mu, \sigma^2)$ be your integral. Then
\begin{align*}
J_m(\mu, \sigma^2) &= \left(1 - \Phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right)\mathbb{E}[X^m|X>0] \\
&=\sum_{r=0}^{m}\binom{m}{r}\mu^{m-r}\sigma^rI_r
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
I_r  = \int_{-\mu/\sigma}^{\infty} t^r \phi(t) dt = \left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)^{r-1}\phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right) + (r-1)I_{r-2}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But what I want to find an upper bound with explicit expression without iterative formula